# how do i get terminal in osx to use the python version installed in /opt/local/bin rather than the one in /usr/bin

Tags: mac-osx, terminal, directory, path

at the moment my $PATH looks like...

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

but then `whereis python2.6` returns `/usr/bin/python`

i need to use /opt/local/bin as this is where macports installs to...

thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think [python_select](http://python_select.darwinports.com/) should sort this for you. It allows you to have MacPorts install all the Python versions, then you choose which one you want to be the default. You can just `sudo port install` it.